# Powershell: Files are being copied into unnamed entity instead of the folder

Tags: powershell

I am copying files from the remote machines, such that only files that are 14 day old are being copied, but for some reason, it copies files into a strange blob (it is not a folder) with names of the `$server`

```
$logdestbase = "W:\PDP\EDWStats\WhatIfLogs\Copies\"
foreach ($server in $allservers) {
    $servermask = "\\$server$logmask" #
    $destfolder = "$logdestbase$server" #where to copy locally
    $logfiles = gci $servermask  #remote folder with files
    foreach ($logfile in $logfiles) {
        copy -path $logfile.fullname -destination $destfolder  #everything works up to this line
```

Comment: Try this: `$destfolder = "$logdestbase$server"` -> `$destfolder = "$logdestbase$server\"`Or even better would be `$destfolder = Join-Path $logdestbase "$server\"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and check :

```
$logdestbase = "W:\PDP\EDWStats\WhatIfLogs\Copies\"
foreach ($server in $allservers) 
{
    $servermask = "\\$server$logmask"
    $destfolder = "$logdestbase$server\"
    $logfiles = get-childitem $servermask 
    foreach ($logfile in $logfiles) 
    {
        copy -path $logfile.fullname -destination $destfolder
    }

}
```